# Como ocultar pasta assets do Cordova

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Olá! Recentemente criei uma APK com Cordova e resolvi olhar o APK com Android Studio e quando abri, todo meu código em javascript e HTML poderia ser exibido. Teria como eu ocultar a pasta assets para que não mostre esses dados pois no javascript tem locais onde é puxado umas APIs?